# Azure DevOps UserEntitlements REST API with filter fails for email adress

Tags: azure, filter, azure-devops, entitlements

I'm trying to retrieve information about a user in Azure DevOps API by filtering on their email address. When I remove the filter, all users are displayed, but I only want to get information about that specific user. How can I do that?

```
api_url = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?$filter=mailAddress eq 'name.example@xxx.com'&api-version=7.0"
```

```
Error while trying to get user ID: b'{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid filter: \\"mailAddress eq \'name.example@xxx.com\'\\"","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Exceptions.InvalidQueryStringException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"InvalidQueryStringException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}'
```

I want to get information about that specific user